# using php code inside a JS file

Tags: javascript, php

I’m trying to use `base_url()` into a javascript file, after I searched about how to do it, I found this solution :

In my page header I print out the `base_url`, as the following :

```
 <script type="text/javascr1pt">
     var base_url='<?php echo base_url() ?>';  
</script>
```

And in my JS file, I do as the following :

```
$(function(){
    $('#logout-button').click(function(event){
        jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url     : base_url + '/index.php/login/logout' ,
            dataType: 'text',
            success : function(data){
                $('#login-loader').hide();
                        //location.reload(true);
            },
            error   : function(){
                $('#error-login').replaceWith('<div id="error-login" class="msg fail"><p>Une erreur a été rencontrée lors du deconnexion!</p></div>');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

But I get this error message :

```
ReferenceError: base_url is not defined
```

So why I'm getting that the variable base_url is not defined ?

When I inspected my page using Firebug, I can see that the variable is defined :

```
<script type="text/javascr1pt">
var base_url='http://localhost/ci/';
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Try `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script type="text/javascr1pt">` When did you include your JS file? Before or after the `base_url`?

Comment: Is the misspelling of the script type as `text/javascr1pt` intentional? (You've got a `1` instead of an `i`.)

Comment: Voting to close as typographical error.

Answer (score 6):

`javascr1pt` is spelt `javascript`.

If you use an unrecognised Content-Type, the script will not be processed as JS.

Since HTML 5, the type attribute is optional for script elements that load JavaScript. You should omit it entirely as its only function here is to give you the opportunity to make a typo like this.